# Track NSWindow focus? (Swift, macOS)

Tags: swift, macos, nswindow, appkit

I'm trying to track a created windows focus so I can perform actions on those events.

I'm able to track a windows frame dimensions with the notification center using `NSView.frameDidChangeNotification`, but I cant find a correct way of using something like `NSWindowDidResignKeyNotification` or `NSWindowDidResignMainNotification`.

```swift
private func newWindow() {
    let windowInfo  = WindowInfo()
    let contentView = ContentView()
        .environmentObject(windowInfo)

    let window = NSWindow(
        contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 350, height: 600),
        styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
        backing: .buffered,
        defer: false
    )

    window.isReleasedWhenClosed                         = false
    window.contentView                                  = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView)
    window.contentView?.postsFrameChangedNotifications  = true
    window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)

    // vvv  I'm trying to use a similar method of being notified when a created window loses/regains focus.  vvv
    //                                                          v v v
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSView.frameDidChangeNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) in
        windowInfo.frame = window.frame
    }
}
```

Also, if theres some method for detecting window focus in SwiftUI, I could use that too. The notifications that actions are performed on are for my Views in SwiftUI

Comment: Post the code you tried please.

Comment: Use  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver has to be used before the window is created to be able to catch notification

Answer (score 0):

This was just a dumb oversight from me (it was pretty late at night), and I found the line I needed.

Adding `NSWindow.didBecomeKeyNotification` did the trick to properly catch the focus events.

Also changing `object: nil` to `object: window` made sure the focus events caught were only for the specific window, instead of all.